# Unable to set "italic fonts" for user interface and terminal in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: fonts

In earlier versions of ubuntu, you could set any type of font (regular, italic, bold etc.) for the user interface using the tweak-tool. Also, the monospace font (such as in terminal, or the gedit app) could be set to any type of font including regular, italic, bold, or combination of these.
But in ubuntu 22.04, you can set only regular type of font as user interface font or monospace font using the tweak-tool, and the italic and bold fonts are not supported, even if you set it in tweak-tool.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Possibly you run into [bug #2019906](https://launchpad.net/bugs/2019906). But according to the reporter of that bug the issue happens only in 23.04, while you talk about 22.04, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I have ubuntu 22.04 installed on my PC and laptop both, and on both, this bug is there. Also, I have linux mint (build on ubuntu 22.04) installed on my third PC, and this bug is there also.

Comment: Please feel free to add your observations to the bug report.